# Is there any document covering Android and Java SDK 1.6 difference in term of classes methods set?

Tags: android

I am developing a tool helping to convert web applications to run them on Android devices using Atjeews Android web application server. I noticed that applications have common problems as

No isEmpty() method for String

No java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MINUTES field and many others.

If I look in Android SDK reference, then all these methods and fields are available, however the SDK reference seems covering Android 3.0.

So will it be true if I can state that all Android versions until 3.0 are JDK 1.5 compatible and I need only assure that I can compile my sources setting bootclass of JDK 1.5 runtime?

Comment: There will still be plenty of things in J2SE that aren't in Android (AWT and Swing are obvious candidates). You might have more luck with J2ME, but even then, that's not a given.

Answer (score 0):

No. Many classes in the JDK are not in Android 3.0 or 3.1 for that matter, and will never be there. If you look [here on page 15](http://manning.com/collins/Android_MEAP_CH01.pdf) (warning: pdf link), you'll find a graphical diff. Disclaimer: That is from a book that I co-wrote.

Comment: Thanks, so here is try and see approach. So I posted other question regarding how prevent application crashing (at least do it gracefully) if some problem like that occured. So far I will test if uncaught handler works. And nice book BTW